# How to replace UNION in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sybase

I have a table: attb

```
------------------------------------------------
Id | Name | Code | Attribute | Amount 
------------------------------------------------
1  | AV   | 123  | Alpha     | 233
------------------------------------------------
2  | TV   | 122  | Beta      | 235
------------------------------------------------
3  | TV   | 123  | Gama      | 238
------------------------------------------------
4  | CD   | 122  | Beta      | 239
------------------------------------------------
5  | TP   | 122  | Beta      | 240
------------------------------------------------
6  | RX   | 123  | Alpha     | 241
------------------------------------------------
```

I'm querying it as:

```
select id,name, code, attribute, amount
from attb
where code = 123 and attribute='Alpha'
UNION
select id,name, code, attribute, amount
from attb
where code = 122;
```

It return the following

---

```
Id | Name | Code | Attribute | Amount 
------------------------------------------------
1  | AV   | 123  | Alpha     | 233
------------------------------------------------
2  | TV   | 122  | Beta      | 235
------------------------------------------------
4  | CD   | 122  | Beta      | 239
------------------------------------------------
5  | TP   | 122  | Beta      | 240
------------------------------------------------
6  | RX   | 123  | Alpha     | 241
------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way I can combine two queries instead of using UNION operator? or Any better implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put both `where` clauses into one query:

```
select id,name, code, attribute, amount
from attb
where (code = 123 and attribute='Alpha') 
   or code = 122;
```

Output:

```
id  name  code  attribute  amount
1   AV    123   Alpha      233 
2   TV    122   Beta       235 
4   CD    122   Beta       239 
5   TP    122   Beta       240 
6   RX    123   Alpha      241
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/778e69/1)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easily. Just use `or`.

```
select id,name, code, attribute, amount
from attb
where (code = 123 and attribute='Alpha') OR code = 122
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select id,name, code, attribute, amount
    from attb
    where ((code = 123 and attribute='Alpha') or (code = 122))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id,name, code, attribute, amount
from attb
where (code IN(122, 123) and attribute='Alpha') ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This does not work, since it would omit rows #5 and #6